# How to get the name of color of web element in selenium webdriver?

Tags: object, selenium, selenium-webdriver, colors

In my project, the requirement is to check the color of web element i.e red, green, pink etc.But using getCssValue() method are getting rgb value in hexadecimal form.Please help me to achieve it.Thank You.

Comment: Of course you will get RGB or color code like #D1DBDF using getCssValue(). i did not see any method to get color name in selenium.

Comment: You can try getting the color name from an external website (like [this](http://name-of-color.com/) website), run a small script to search for the hex on the site and scrape the color name.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to help you we need to see the code you've tried. That way we can show you how to alter it to do what you want. here's a guide on how to ask questions on Stack Overflow in a way that you will get what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is to write a script that will query a website like - http://name-of-color.com/ with the hex code and parse the html code and retrieve the Color name that is displayed on the website.

So, overall the steps would be:

1. Get the hex code (You already have it)
2. Query the website as follows (you could use the URL, URLConnection class for this OR you could use Selenium+PhantomJS OR Jsoup)

   URL: http://name-of-color.com/?hex=#F89406
3. Scrape the html page source and get the color name that is displayed on the website

Answer (score 0):

For getting the the name of the color you can use this class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ColorUtils {

    private static ArrayList<ColorName> initColorList() {
        ArrayList<ColorName> colorList = new ArrayList<>();
        colorList.add(new ColorName("AliceBlue", 0xF0, 0xF8, 0xFF));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("AntiqueWhite", 0xFA, 0xEB, 0xD7));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Aqua", 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Aquamarine", 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xD4));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Azure", 0xF0, 0xFF, 0xFF));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Beige", 0xF5, 0xF5, 0xDC));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Bisque", 0xFF, 0xE4, 0xC4));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Black", 0x00, 0x00, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("BlanchedAlmond", 0xFF, 0xEB, 0xCD));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Blue", 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("BlueViolet", 0x8A, 0x2B, 0xE2));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Brown", 0xA5, 0x2A, 0x2A));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("BurlyWood", 0xDE, 0xB8, 0x87));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("CadetBlue", 0x5F, 0x9E, 0xA0));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Chartreuse", 0x7F, 0xFF, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Chocolate", 0xD2, 0x69, 0x1E));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Coral", 0xFF, 0x7F, 0x50));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("CornflowerBlue", 0x64, 0x95, 0xED));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Cornsilk", 0xFF, 0xF8, 0xDC));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Crimson", 0xDC, 0x14, 0x3C));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Cyan", 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkBlue", 0x00, 0x00, 0x8B));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkCyan", 0x00, 0x8B, 0x8B));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkGoldenRod", 0xB8, 0x86, 0x0B));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkGray", 0xA9, 0xA9, 0xA9));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkGreen", 0x00, 0x64, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkKhaki", 0xBD, 0xB7, 0x6B));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkMagenta", 0x8B, 0x00, 0x8B));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkOliveGreen", 0x55, 0x6B, 0x2F));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkOrange", 0xFF, 0x8C, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkOrchid", 0x99, 0x32, 0xCC));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkRed", 0x8B, 0x00, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkSalmon", 0xE9, 0x96, 0x7A));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkSeaGreen", 0x8F, 0xBC, 0x8F));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkSlateBlue", 0x48, 0x3D, 0x8B));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkSlateGray", 0x2F, 0x4F, 0x4F));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkTurquoise", 0x00, 0xCE, 0xD1));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkViolet", 0x94, 0x00, 0xD3));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DeepPink", 0xFF, 0x14, 0x93));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DeepSkyBlue", 0x00, 0xBF, 0xFF));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DimGray", 0x69, 0x69, 0x69));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DodgerBlue", 0x1E, 0x90, 0xFF));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("FireBrick", 0xB2, 0x22, 0x22));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("FloralWhite", 0xFF, 0xFA, 0xF0));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("ForestGreen", 0x22, 0x8B, 0x22));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Fuchsia", 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Gainsboro", 0xDC, 0xDC, 0xDC));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("GhostWhite", 0xF8, 0xF8, 0xFF));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Gold", 0xFF, 0xD7, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("GoldenRod", 0xDA, 0xA5, 0x20));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Gray", 0x80, 0x80, 0x80));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Green", 0x00, 0x80, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("GreenYellow", 0xAD, 0xFF, 0x2F));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("HoneyDew", 0xF0, 0xFF, 0xF0));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("HotPink", 0xFF, 0x69, 0xB4));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("IndianRed", 0xCD, 0x5C, 0x5C));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Indigo", 0x4B, 0x00, 0x82));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Ivory", 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF0));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Khaki", 0xF0, 0xE6, 0x8C));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Lavender", 0xE6, 0xE6, 0xFA));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LavenderBlush", 0xFF, 0xF0, 0xF5));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LawnGreen", 0x7C, 0xFC, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LemonChiffon", 0xFF, 0xFA, 0xCD));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightBlue", 0xAD, 0xD8, 0xE6));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightCoral", 0xF0, 0x80, 0x80));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightCyan", 0xE0, 0xFF, 0xFF));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightGoldenRodYellow", 0xFA, 0xFA, 0xD2));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightGray", 0xD3, 0xD3, 0xD3));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightGreen", 0x90, 0xEE, 0x90));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightPink", 0xFF, 0xB6, 0xC1));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightSalmon", 0xFF, 0xA0, 0x7A));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightSeaGreen", 0x20, 0xB2, 0xAA));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightSkyBlue", 0x87, 0xCE, 0xFA));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightSlateGray", 0x77, 0x88, 0x99));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightSteelBlue", 0xB0, 0xC4, 0xDE));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightYellow", 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE0));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Lime", 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LimeGreen", 0x32, 0xCD, 0x32));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Linen", 0xFA, 0xF0, 0xE6));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Magenta", 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Maroon", 0x80, 0x00, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumAquaMarine", 0x66, 0xCD, 0xAA));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumBlue", 0x00, 0x00, 0xCD));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumOrchid", 0xBA, 0x55, 0xD3));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumPurple", 0x93, 0x70, 0xDB));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumSeaGreen", 0x3C, 0xB3, 0x71));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumSlateBlue", 0x7B, 0x68, 0xEE));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumSpringGreen", 0x00, 0xFA, 0x9A));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumTurquoise", 0x48, 0xD1, 0xCC));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumVioletRed", 0xC7, 0x15, 0x85));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("MidnightBlue", 0x19, 0x19, 0x70));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("MintCream", 0xF5, 0xFF, 0xFA));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("MistyRose", 0xFF, 0xE4, 0xE1));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Moccasin", 0xFF, 0xE4, 0xB5));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("NavajoWhite", 0xFF, 0xDE, 0xAD));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Navy", 0x00, 0x00, 0x80));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("OldLace", 0xFD, 0xF5, 0xE6));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Olive", 0x80, 0x80, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("OliveDrab", 0x6B, 0x8E, 0x23));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Orange", 0xFF, 0xA5, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("OrangeRed", 0xFF, 0x45, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Orchid", 0xDA, 0x70, 0xD6));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("PaleGoldenRod", 0xEE, 0xE8, 0xAA));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("PaleGreen", 0x98, 0xFB, 0x98));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("PaleTurquoise", 0xAF, 0xEE, 0xEE));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("PaleVioletRed", 0xDB, 0x70, 0x93));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("PapayaWhip", 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xD5));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("PeachPuff", 0xFF, 0xDA, 0xB9));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Peru", 0xCD, 0x85, 0x3F));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Pink", 0xFF, 0xC0, 0xCB));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Plum", 0xDD, 0xA0, 0xDD));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("PowderBlue", 0xB0, 0xE0, 0xE6));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Purple", 0x80, 0x00, 0x80));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Red", 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("RosyBrown", 0xBC, 0x8F, 0x8F));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("RoyalBlue", 0x41, 0x69, 0xE1));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("SaddleBrown", 0x8B, 0x45, 0x13));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Salmon", 0xFA, 0x80, 0x72));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("SandyBrown", 0xF4, 0xA4, 0x60));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("SeaGreen", 0x2E, 0x8B, 0x57));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("SeaShell", 0xFF, 0xF5, 0xEE));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Sienna", 0xA0, 0x52, 0x2D));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Silver", 0xC0, 0xC0, 0xC0));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("SkyBlue", 0x87, 0xCE, 0xEB));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("SlateBlue", 0x6A, 0x5A, 0xCD));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("SlateGray", 0x70, 0x80, 0x90));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Snow", 0xFF, 0xFA, 0xFA));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("SpringGreen", 0x00, 0xFF, 0x7F));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("SteelBlue", 0x46, 0x82, 0xB4));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Tan", 0xD2, 0xB4, 0x8C));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Teal", 0x00, 0x80, 0x80));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Thistle", 0xD8, 0xBF, 0xD8));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Tomato", 0xFF, 0x63, 0x47));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Turquoise", 0x40, 0xE0, 0xD0));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Violet", 0xEE, 0x82, 0xEE));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Wheat", 0xF5, 0xDE, 0xB3));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("White", 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("WhiteSmoke", 0xF5, 0xF5, 0xF5));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Yellow", 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("YellowGreen", 0x9A, 0xCD, 0x32));
        return colorList;
    }

    public static String getColorNameFromRgb(int r, int g, int b) {
        ArrayList<ColorName> colorList = initColorList();
        ColorName closestMatch = null;
        int minMSE = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int mse;
        for (ColorName c : colorList) {
            mse = c.computeMSE(r, g, b);
            if (mse < minMSE) {
                minMSE = mse;
                closestMatch = c;
            }
        }

        if (closestMatch != null) {
            return closestMatch.getName();
        } else {
            return "No matched color name.";
        }
    }

    public static String getColorNameFromColor(Color color) {
        return getColorNameFromRgb(color.getRed(), color.getGreen(),
                color.getBlue());
    }

    public static Color stringToColor(final String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return Color.black;
        }
        try {
            return Color.decode(value);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            try {
                final Field f = Color.class.getField(value);
                return (Color) f.get(null);
            } catch (Exception ce) {
                return Color.black;
            }
        }
    }

public static class ColorName {
    public int r, g, b;
    public String name;

    public ColorName(String name, int r, int g, int b) {
        this.r = r;
        this.g = g;
        this.b = b;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int computeMSE(int pixR, int pixG, int pixB) {
        return ((pixR - r) * (pixR - r) + (pixG - g) * (pixG - g) + (pixB - b)
                * (pixB - b)) / 3;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
}
```

And finally, the method should be like this:

```
public String getElementColor(WebElement element) {
    
        String color = element.getCssValue("color");
        String hex = Color.fromString(color).asHex();
        java.awt.Color c = stringToColor(hex);
        return getColorNameFromColor(c);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Swetha,

You will always get the color code with getCssValue(), if you want the color name, you could write a simple code to convert it. like i was refering one site for this, try this code-

```
string GetColorName(Color color)
{
var colorProperties = typeof(Color)
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(Color));
foreach(var colorProperty in colorProperties) 
{
    var colorPropertyValue = (Color)colorProperty.GetValue(null, null);
    if(colorPropertyValue.R == color.R 
           && colorPropertyValue.G == color.G 
           && colorPropertyValue.B == color.B) {
        return colorPropertyValue.Name;
    }
}

//If unknown color, fallback to the hex value
//(or you could return null, "Unkown" or whatever you want)
return ColorTranslator.ToHtml(color);
}
```